# Use updated variable values in Dart in globally defined functions

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am not sure how to word this exactly, but essentially, I have defined 3 global variables as:

```
String Date = '2022-08-12';
int Hour = 00;
```

and I have a function(X) at the end of the file, where I am using these variables. However, before that function(x) is run I am redefining these variables through some other function. Now in function(x) I want to use these new updated values, but dart refuses to use the updated values in function(x) even though function(x) is called after the function that is changing the values of these variables.

A few things to mention function(x) is globally defined in the file.

So to summarize, my question here is How do I make it such that when this function(x) is run it is using these updated variable values, and not the original ones (that were used to initialise those variables)? Thanks :)

Edit: For further clarification, the function is being passed in as a parameter to a function which will be called later.

More Code for reference:

```
void setAlarm() async{
  Date = '2028-12-12';
  Hour = '13'
  await alarm.AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(alarmTime, 1, fireAlarm);
}

void fireAlarm(){
  print(Date); // This is still = 2022-08-12 even though the function is being called after the value has been reassgined
  print(Hour);// This is still = 00 even though the function is being called after the value has been reassgined
}
```

Comment: Please upload a full example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: please add your code too.

Comment: @julemand101 can you check the post now?

Comment: @eamirho3ein can you check the post now?

Comment: @eamirho3ein You are never calling `setAlarm()` in your example.

Comment: @julemand101 setAlarm() is being called through the press of a button, which I have not shown here, but the function is being called.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Generally speaking, don't use global variables. Use proper state management.

Answer (score 0):

My strong guess is that you call setAlarm first and then fireAlarm. Since setAlarm is async, you need to await setAlarm to finish, before you call setAlarm